# validate number and currency with regex

Tags: java, regex, currency

I'm working on a regex but don't know exactly what to do further.
These are my regex: 
1) `"^-?\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{3})*(?:,\\d+)?\\s$";`
2) `"^-?\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{3})*(?:,\\d+)?\\s\\€$"`
3) `"[0-9.,]*"`
4) `"[0-9.,€]*"`

these regex check either for currency String or numbers.
Example to each one
1) 123.456,99
2) 123.456,99 €
3) 12,19
4) 12,19 €

Each regex works for the related example.
Is there a posibility to combine all those regex to one?
and how can i make this regex flexible to whitespaces at any position in that string.

thx in advance

Sami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`^-?(\d{1,3}\s*?([.,]|$|\\s)\\s*?)+€?$`](https://regex101.com/r/doFgv6/5)

- `^-?(\\d{1,3}\\s*?([.,]|$|\\s)\\s*?)+€?$` : `^` starts with

  - `(\\d{1,3}\s*?([.,]|$|\\s)\\s*?)+` match one or more pair of digits, separated by `.` or `,`
  - `\\d{1,3}\\s*?` match digits between 1 to 3 , match spaces as less as possible
  - `([.,]|$|\s)\\s*?` zero or one match of `.` or `,` or end or space , `\\s*?` zero or more spaces
- `€?$` zero or one match of `€` character , `$` end of match

[**Java Demo**](http://ideone.com/eVm3lS)

Comment: please be specific about issues and check out the `java Demo` link in the answer to see the working state

Comment: ok thank you @Pavneet_Singh. i will test it and will give you later a detailed  feedback. thx

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

`\d{1,3}(?:.|,)+€?`

and for java it should be `"\\d{1,3}(?:.|,)+€?"`

I highly recommend http://regexr.com for all your regex needs. They have a great "cheatsheet" and a nice testing environment

Comment: you might want to escape `.` this doesn't mean a dot character

Comment: try it with `12, aaa asbbsbb19 €` , `.`  mean any character , and OP also don't realize it now

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh you right. alpha numeric charachters are not alowed. only the Euro sign (€) and white space only after the number or between number and euro sign. thx